# How to implement a deterministic finite automaton class in C++

Tags: c++, dfa

I'm trying to implement a deterministic finite automaton in C++. Here's what I have:

```
typedef unsigned int state;

class Dfa {
    private:
        std::set<state> states;                                   // \(Q = q_0 q_1 q_2 \ldots q_{N - 1} \)
        std::set<char> alphabet;                                  // \(\Sigma\)
        state initial;                                            // \(q_0\)
        std::set<state> accept;                                   // \(F\)
        std::function<std::optional<state>(state, char)> delta;   // \(\delta(q, i)\)

    public:
        d_recognize();
};
```

According to the "Speech and Language Processing", by Daniel Jurafsky and James H. Martin, delta can be either a transition function or matrix. The closest parallel in C++ imo is a `map<pair<unsigned int, char>, unsigned int>`. So I want delta to be either a `function<optional<unsigned int>(unsigned int, char)>` or a `map<pair<unsigned int, char>, unsigned int>`. I think that this might be a good time to use concepts in C++, but I'm not actually sure how to write a concept that accepts both a `function<optional<unsigned int>(unsigned int, char)>` or a `map<pair<unsigned int, char>, unsigned int>`. How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you do not necessarily need a `std::function`. Any function or callable that returns an `optional<unsigned int>` for given `(unsigned int, char)` will do. I don't know DFA, but options are:

- precalculate the values to have them readily available in a map, or
- calculate them when needed with a function, or
- combine both and use a function that internally uses a map for memoization.

Your choice. Do you need the result only for a small subset of input? Then a map will waste memory. Is the function expensive to calculate? Then perhaps a go for a function with memoization.